# asp.net accepting form posts from another domain

Tags: asp.net

I'm working with a WordPress site at the moment that has a form for which I want the data redirected. Put another way, I'm looking to have a PHP form submitted to an Asp.net web page. Is this possible?

The form is created with a WordPress plugin called Contact Form 7

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can do a POST to the ASP.NET page, and on that page you would just need to use Request.Form to access the posted values. You could also do a GET and grab them through Request.QueryString.

For security reasons, you might want to check the source where things are coming from on the ASP.NET page to make sure it's coming from the WordPress site.

Comment: What would you suggest in terms of verifying the source? Checking the source host name? or IP address?

Comment: @Jacques I've checked either one, Host name or IP Address. Both could be faked if someone had enough desire, but I'd say they are relatively safe to check.

Answer (score 1):

If its a normal HTTP Post you are talking about it should not matter what the end system is running on. Here are some info about creating a POST event from PHP

http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/